# Bypass Software Wizard and Install with Default Parameters

Tags: python, powershell, docker, wizard

I would like to create a script which will download a piece of software, docker, and install it on my PC.  I can do it by using dockers installation wizard, but I'm wondering how I can bypass the wizard and just install it.  Is this possible?

The wizard accepts a few commands such as selecting main and additional components. Is there any way I can set these as parameters in a python script and pass them to the wizard?  Once again, the intention is an executable python script that just installs the software without the user having to select anything via the traditional wizard.

I'm not looking for anyone to write a script for me to accomplish this, but rather point me in the right direction so I can create it myself.  I don't have the first idea about how to install the software without the wizard GUI.

**Link to the Toolbox/ Wizard**

https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [issue #322](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/322) the installer was created with Inno Setup, so launching it with the `/silent` or `/verysilent` parameter should make it run non-interactively. Run the executable with the option `/?` or check the [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline) to see a list of all commandline parameters.